# Can you not pass argments to commands using keys?

Tags: macros, xparse, pgfkeys, arguments

I use my own `LaTeX` preamble for university, so I am fairly used to creating macros using tools such as `xparse`. However, I am unsure why I cannot do something that will choose between two images on my behalf.

The idea is that I have a global boolean to set everything to a style of "dark mode", which I use while working on a draft. Essentially, all that matters is that I have

```latex
\setboolean{DARKMODE}{true}
```

I use an SVG to style up my paper a bit (the details for this are unimportant). I have a light and dark mode version of an SVG and use the `svg` package for this (I do this because, from my understanding, you cannot set the SVG's colour from within `LaTeX`).

Currently, I have the following:

```latex
\newcommand{\AddSvgHeight}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{DARKMODE}}{%
        \includesvg[height=#1px]{MySvg_White}
    }{%                      
        \includesvg[height=#1px]{MySvg_Black}
    }
}
```

I want to pass the argument (the width) to the height key used by the `\includesvg` command. However, I get the error:

> Package scrbase Error: unknown option height=['. \OtherCommand

where `\OtherCommand` is the command that uses this command.

I have tried several variants with the same or similar problems. Why is this happening? How can I go about defining this command?

Comment: `height={#1}px` maybe?  Or `\setlegnth{\dimen0}{#1px}`?  Hard to guess with nothing useful to test it on.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I did try the first one, which gave the same error. The second gave me `Missing number, treated as zero.`, and a whole load of others. I think the way to go is with pgfkeys, but I am not familiar with it, unfortunately. I have a working example that I threw together just now, but it feels overkill. I will answer my own question later when I am confident in this approach and if no one else has any other ideas.

Comment: Note that I misspelled `\setlength`.  What are you passing as #1?

Comment: @JohnKormylo All good, I noticed the typo. I am doing `AddSvgHeight[25px]`. Using pgf keys I see I can instead do `AddSvgHeight[height=20px]`, but that is much more complicated to understand. However, doing it that way does mean I can pass height or width, which I have noticed that I am actually doing in places in my document, so this may be the preferred way. Otherwise, I will need to manage optional parameters and pass those to keys if they are defined, which I think will give the current issue I am having.

Comment: The unit px is hardcoded in your macro, so probably `\AddSvgHeight{25}` might work. If you provide a full compilable example where the error/problem can be reproduced by compiling, one might be able to track the problem down. || Why do you wish to pass the **width** (what width?) to the key `height`? Shouldn't some TeX-dimension quantity be passed whose value denotes the desired **height**?

Comment: The error message mentioned looks like s.th. like `\includesvg[{height=[}=...#1px]{MySvg_White}` is done. Probably some confusion regarding square brackets both coming along with some user-provided argument and being hardcoded into the definition-text.

Comment: I retried an earlier attempted solution, and it works. I am ashamed I didn't retry sooner, but I greatly appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Does LaTeX even recognize px as a unit?  On page 57 of the TeXbook it lists pt, pc, in, bp, cm, mm, dd, cc, and sp (65536sp=1pt).  No px.

Comment: @JohnKormylo TeX-engines based on pdfTeX or luaTeX provide an extra unit called px that takes the dimension given to the `\pdfpxdimen` (pdfTeX)/`\pxdimen` (luaTeX) primitive. (Afaik by default 1px=1pb=(1/72) in.)

Answer (score 1):

I must have made some typo because I am certain I did this, which works as I have wanted it to. I decided to retry the *obvious* solution:

```latex
\newcommand{\AddSvgHeight}[1][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{DARKMODE}}{%
        \includesvg[#1]{Pengu_White}%
    }{%                      
        \includesvg[#1]{Pengu_Black}%
    }%
}
```

It allows me to use any key-value options, which is better than manually passing them, in my case.

Comment: If arbitrary tokens provided by the user might form components of an optional argument, wrap the entire optional argument into curly braces to make sure square-brackets coming along with some user-input also processing optional arguments don't erroneously match the ones hardcoded in your macro-definition, i.e., `\includesvg[{#1}]{Pengu_White}%`. Curly braces surrounding an entire macro argument are stripped off in the processing, no matter if mandatory or optional arguments.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Excellent, I didn't know that. Thanks!